# How to assert HashMap keys to be Comparable with ArchUnit?

Tags: java, archunit

Background: https://dev.to/carey/java-map-keys-should-always-be-comparable-2c1b

What I want to achieve:

1. Find code that uses HashMap.
2. Figure out the type of the HashMaps key.
3. Check if the key type implements Comparable interface.
4. (optional) Check if that type resides in a certain package.

I a stuck at step 2

```
noClasses().that()
        .containAnyFieldsThat(have(rawType(HashMap.class)))
        .should()...
```

Any ideas how I can get the type of a generic class? Thanks for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial part of your `ArchRule` (which can be directly based on [`fields()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/ArchRuleDefinition.html#fields()) or [`codeUnits()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/ArchRuleDefinition.html#codeUnits())) can be expressed with custom [`ArchCondition`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/ArchCondition.html)s:

```java
@ArchTest
static final ArchRule fields_of_type_HashMap_should_have_Comparable_key = fields()
    .that().haveRawType(HashMap.class)
    .should(haveComparableFirstTypeParameter());

@ArchTest
static final ArchRule code_units_should_have_parameters_of_type_HashMap_with_Comparable_key = codeUnits()
    .should(new ArchCondition<JavaCodeUnit>("have parameters of type HashMap with Comparable key") {
        @Override
        public void check(JavaCodeUnit javaCodeUnit, ConditionEvents events) {
            javaCodeUnit.getParameters().forEach(parameter -> {
                if (parameter.getRawType().isEquivalentTo(HashMap.class)) {
                    haveComparableFirstTypeParameter().check(parameter, events);
                }
            });
        }
    });

@ArchTest
static final ArchRule methods_with_return_type_HashMap_should_have_return_types_with_Comparable_key = methods()
    .that().haveRawReturnType(HashMap.class)
    .should(new ArchCondition<JavaMethod>("have return type with Comparable key") {
        @Override
        public void check(JavaMethod method, ConditionEvents events) {
            class ReturnType implements HasType, HasDescription {
                @Override
                public JavaType getType() { return method.getReturnType(); }
                @Override
                public JavaClass getRawType() { return method.getRawReturnType(); }
                @Override
                public String getDescription() { return "Return type <" + getType().getName() + "> of " + method.getDescription(); }
            }
            haveComparableFirstTypeParameter().check(new ReturnType(), events);
        }
    });

private static <T extends HasType & HasDescription> ArchCondition<T> haveComparableFirstTypeParameter() {
    return new ArchCondition<T>("have Comparable first type parameter") {
        @Override
        public void check(T typed, ConditionEvents events) {
            JavaType fieldType = typed.getType();
            if (fieldType instanceof JavaParameterizedType) {
                JavaType keyType = ((JavaParameterizedType) fieldType).getActualTypeArguments().get(0);
                boolean satisfied = keyType.toErasure().getAllRawInterfaces().stream()
                        .anyMatch(rawInterface -> rawInterface.isEquivalentTo(Comparable.class));
                String message = String.format("%s has a first type parameter %s that %s Comparable",
                        typed.getDescription(), keyType.getName(), satisfied ? "is" : "is not");
                events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(typed, satisfied, message));
            } else {
                events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(typed, typed.getDescription() + " is not parameterized"));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! However, this only covers fields of a class, so for example local variables in a method are missed. I tried `codeUnits()` but this does not find them, too. Is there an `ArchRuleDefinition` for arbitrary variable declarations?

Comment: `codeUnits()` only [comprise](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_domain) `methods()`, `constructors()` and static initializers; ArchUnit does currently not analyze local variables.
 The suggested rule can, however, be generalized to method/constructor parameters and method return types; I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thx! I would add a check to `haveComparableFirstTypeParameter()` to deal with generic return types like `public <K, V> Map<K, V> createHashMap()`: 

```
JavaClass erasedType = keyType.toErasure();
List<JavaClass> classHierarchy = erasedType.getClassHierarchy();
boolean isGenericType = classHierarchy.size() == 1;
boolean isRelevant = isGenericType || satisfied;
```

Comment: I proposed a slightly changed (check for keyType instanceof JavaTypeVariable) version to be included in the default ArchUnit rules https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/769